# SQL COUNT in Drupal

Tags: php, sql, drupal, count

I want to create a SQL statement for Drupal with COUNT like this

```
(SELECT COUNT(id) reservas FROM booking WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2014-05-20 00:00:00' AND '2014-05-20 23:55:55') UNION
  (SELECT COUNT(id) reservas FROM booking WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2014-05-21 00:00:00' AND '2014-05-21 23:55:55')
```

For the first part, I tried this, but nothing is returned:

```
$query = db_select('booking', 'b')
    ->fields('b', array('id'))
    ->condition('datetime', array($dates[0] . ' 00:00:00', $dates[0] . ' 23:59:55'), 'BETWEEN');
$query->addExpression('COUNT(id)', 'reservas');
$query->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make an union you must first make one query for the first statement and one for the second and than union them as something like this:

```
$query1 = db_select('booking', 'b')
->fields('b', array('id'))
->condition('datetime', array($dates[0] . ' 00:00:00', $dates[0] . ' 23:59:55'), 'BETWEEN');
$query1->addExpression('COUNT(id)', 'reservas');

$query2 = db_select('booking', 'b')
->fields('b', array('id'))
->condition('datetime', array($dates[0] . ' 00:00:00', $dates[0] . ' 23:59:55'), 'BETWEEN');
$query1->addExpression('COUNT(id)', 'reservas');

$query1->union($query2, 'UNION ALL');
$result = $query1->execute();
```